# How to fix syntax error in python around elif?

Tags: python, windows, syntax-error

I cannot understand this syntax error in python.

```
#I typed this...
elif self.x > 0:
    if self.y != 0:
            self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                                        image=self.images_right[2])
```

when this code is typed, I get...

```
Traceback (most recent call back):
    File "<pyshell#12>",line 245, in <module>
        elif self.x > 0:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I indented in various ways, but that does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`elif` only works if you have the appropriate `if` before, e.g.:

```
if self.x < 0:
    pass
elif self.x > 0:
   ...
```

Seems like you miss the `if` here.

Comment: I only showed part code,actually I added if  before that

Comment: Please update the question to show the full `if` clause.

Comment: Well, i cannot see that in your question. So only thing I can do is guessing.

Comment: elif self.x > 0:
            if self.y != 0:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                                            image=self.images_right[2])
this  is it

Comment: Please update the question to show the full `if` clause.

Comment: Well, i cannot see that in your question. So only thing I can do is guessing.